# Copying coded value for field and not raw value?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, esri-geodatabase

I am working with ArcGIS 10 and I have added a field in a feature class and am attempting to copy the text from another field's coded values, but the field calculator is simply copying the "code" text from the source field and not the "value" text from the domain rule.

Answer (score 4):

Try this tool: [Calculate Domain Code Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=E4AE7F2C-1422-2418-A01E-D201137C303B)

**Update:** Since the tool does the opposite of what you want, you can either tweak it to calculate the description instead of the coded value, or do it interactively:

1. Use [Domain to Table (Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000022000000) to export the domain in question to a table
2. Use [Add Join (Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000064000000) or the [Join Data dialog](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Essentials_of_joining_tables/005s0000002p000000/) to join the table to your feature class on the code field
3. Use [Calculate Field (Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004m000000) or the [Field Calculator dialog](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Making_simple_field_calculations/005s00000026000000/) to calculate the field you want the descriptions to go in, entering the joined table's description field in the expression box.
4. (Optional) Remove the join and delete the table you created

Comment: Actually that looks like it might do the opposite of what you want... you might have to mess with it to get it to do the reverse.

Comment: Rather than steps 2 (Add Join) and 3 (Calc Field) I would do in single step using Join Field tool.  Step 1 would stay the same and optional 4 would only need to Delete the table.

Comment: Good point! I always forget about that tool. The only reason you wouldn't want to use Join Field is if the column already exists, since Join Field will create new columns, even if they already exist, by appending a number after the name.

Comment: first link is broken, does that tool have another name? It's what I need right now